# How to get a customized counter

Tags: counters

I would like to change my equation counter for a specific chapter to a customized one, for example: EQ.1, EQ.2, EQ.3.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `\renewcommand{\theequation}{Eq.\arabic{equation}}` to make the change, and then `\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{equation}}` to change it back.

Comment: You coul also use `\let\oldtheequation=\theequation` before the redefinition and then restore it to its previous definition (without actually knowing it yourself) with `\let\theequation=\oldtheequation`. (The '`=`' are optional in both cases)